# Assembly instruction MOV BL,0

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a problem about Assembly instruction .I  don't understand why in this exercice the instruction MOV BL,0 conteins already the actual maximum . Following the code :

```
    SECTION data
    Vect1: db 13,15,22,7,5,3,21,2,0,10
    Vect2: db 1,7,3,2,22,21,3,28,7,11
    string1: db ‘ maximum is in the vector 1’,0
    string2: db ‘maximum is in the vector 2’,0
    SECTION text
    ..start:
    ...
    FindMax:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov si,[bp+6] ; Vect1
    mov di,[bp+4] ; Vect2
    mov bl,0 ; bl conteins the actual maximum ->>>WHY??
    mov cx,[bp+8] ; N = 10

    Loop:
mov ah,[si]
cmp ah, bl
ja NewMaximum1

LoopRef1:
inc si
mov ah,[di]
cmp ah,bl
ja NewMaximum2

LoopRef2:
inc di
loop Loop
jmp endFunc

NewMaximum1:
mov bl,ah
mov al, 0
jmp LoopRef1

NewMaximum2:
mov bl,ah
mov al, 1
jmp LoopRef2
endFunc:
pop bp
ret
```

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: At the start of the function, no elements have been inspected yet, so there is no maximum. You left the irrelevant code and deleted the relevant code!

Comment: yes now i post it .

Comment: Notice that in the FindMax procedure, there is a label called "new maximum".

Comment: this is the other part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using unsigned compares, and `0` is the lowest possible unsigned number.  It's normal to start a max-finding loop with `max=0` or `max=INT_MIN`, instead of loading the first element, because that simplifies handling the case where the input is zero length.

It looks like there's a bug if both arrays contain all zeros: it would never set AL to 0 or 1 to record which array had the maximum.  But probably it's just branching on AL to decide which string to print, so you get a random one depending on what was in AL to start with.

It would have been a lot more efficient to do `mov al, '1'` or `mov al, '2'`, and store AL to the relevant position in the string after the search, but then you would need to make sure it was initialized in case the search loop never found a new max candidate above `0`.